# Primary key ID missing from row or is null idiorm

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, idiorm

```
    $user=ORM::forTable('users')->where('usermail',$email)->findOne();
    $user->set('email',$email);
    $user->set('password',$password);
    $user->save();
```

Есть код. Нужно обновить запись в sqlite через idiorm. При попытке сделать это, выдаёт такую ошибку: **Primary key ID missing from row or is null idiorm**

Читал где-то, что надо что-то конфигурировать, но не разобрался, поэтому пишу сюда с просьбой о помощи!

Comment: Вы ищите пользователя по email и потом этот же email вставляете в другое поле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагается, что поле первичного ключа называется id. Если у вас другое поле для первичного ключа, то надо его указать.

```
ORM::configure('id_column', 'primary_key');
```

http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#id-column